# Name of person who gives subsidy?

Tags: meaning

What is the proper name of the person who gives subsidy to someone?

Most times this is given by some Ministry, but an individual can also give subsidy to someone.

Comment: Patron, subsidizer, etc.

Comment: They are often called **the subsidy provider**.

Comment: In my line of work, in the UK, we would generally say 'the subsidising body'. This tends to work even if the subsidy is apparently provided by an individual as there will most often be some sort of intermediary Trust which legaly disburses funds rather than a direct personal transaction.

Comment: Why are these answers in comments?

Answer (score 1):

Subsidizer (or the modern UK subsidiser spelling) is to found in use in 1871 by lieutenant John Layland Needham in his translation from Rustow's original German work, The War for the Rhine frontier 1870. William Blackwood & Sons, 1871, p.138

> "Naturally this *journal entretenu* must have an *entreteneur* [publisher's original italics] and this **subsidiser** was no other than the Emperor Napolean himself."

So it seems subsidiser is a perfectly legitimate term to refer to a person or organisation providing a subsidy.